# unable to decrypt Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop while im logged as user owner?

Tags: permissions, ssh, password, encryption, ubuntu-mate

i have ubuntu mate 16 on rpi 3 installed in usb stick,

after turning the sytem down properly, this morning i'm surprised with ssh doesn't allow me to access (im 100% the password is correct), so i did reboot the system to emergencey mode to gain root access in order to reset my password, after the reboot i have logged in , but my home directory is encrpted !
also it's been a long time that im using the system and i forgot the pass key that i did :/

any suggestion to unlock my directory ? ! its completly weired it must be decrypted since now im logged in as user owner !

```
agentsimo@x:~$ uname -a
Linux x 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

also apt upgrade has some errors :

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package 'gzip' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Related: [can't log in after password change (ecryptfs)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281491/cant-log-in-after-password-change-ecryptfs), [Changed password - now can't login to my account (full disk encyption + encrypted home folder)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766857/changed-password-now-cant-login-to-my-account-full-disk-encyption-encrypte)

Comment: You are having problems because you have an encrypted home directory and you went and changed your user password without reading about such encryption. You have to decrypt your home directory manually after logging in via ssh. You have to change your password with graphical tools. This is to prevent root from accessing your data by changing your password. Change your password back and read up on encrypted home directories and ssh

Comment: @Panther thank you ! i did rest back the password that was before , and then i logged in using graphical interface , now my data are decrypted :D