# Can't log in after changed password

Tags: login, password

I've tried to change my user's password, with the help of [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword). It seems that it was lucky, because when I'm entering the new password, [Ubuntu get stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).

But what's next? I've tried totally everything from question above, I have only two files in my user's directory: Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop and README.txt, that's all.

How can I exit that loop?

Comment: You will need to re-wrap your passphrase - see [can't log in after password change (ecryptfs)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281491/cant-log-in-after-password-change-ecryptfs)